# Are Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings values interned strings?

Tags: c#, string, garbage-collection, runtime

I read a lot about the behavior of strings in .Net. I knew that literal strings `var s = "Hello World!"` are interned per default and even if my application no longer reference it, the string will never collected by the garbage collector.

What happens to strings which are read from the App.config? Are those strings constructed at runtime?

Does `s` behaves like other managed objects and get cleaned up, if no reference exists?

`var s = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Hello World!"]`

Comment: What does String.IsInterned(s) return?

Comment: @eric-j That's easy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Configuration strings are regular strings and constructed at run-time - configuration files are not compiled into assemblies, so will not be interned by compiler.

Note that in general the fact that string is not coming from compiled source says nothing about whether such strings are interned or not as code can decide to intern strings manually at run-time with [`String.Intern`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I don't expect config parsing code to ever intern string - should be easy to check with [`String.IsInterned`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isinterned%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) call if want to be completely sure.

If really curious you can try to dig through the source starting from [ConfigurationManager.AppSettings](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Configuration/System/Configuration/ConfigurationManager.cs,cfa8b7126ec13177,references), but prepare to spend some time as there are interfaces involved obscuring direct navigation in the source.

Comment: Thanks a lot, dosen't know anything about `String.IsInterned`.